# System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found

Tags: postgresql, unity-game-engine, dll

I have this game that uses npgsql.dll for database and I'm trying to build the game and the following error shows up:

> ArgumentException: The Assembly System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions is
>   referenced by Npgsql ('Assets/plugin/Npgsql.dll'). But the dll is not
>   allowed to be included or could not be found.
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse
>   (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List1[T]
>   alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths,
>   System.String[] foldersToSearch,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue] cache,
>   UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:150)
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[]
>   paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
>   target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:190)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

I have both dll(Npgsql.dll and System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll) in Assets\Plugins

Comment: Which .Net version do you use?

Comment: found any solution on this?